# C# Windows 8.1 Background Task that runs while the device screen is locked

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I've done a lot of work over the past week, working with creating background task for a windows universal project. I've having a hard, and starting believe it is not possible triggering a background task to run when the device screen is locked. I'm using SystemTriggerType.Useraway to trigger the background task. I'll post what i've got so far. Any help with this would be awesome!

Here's how I am registering the background task

```
    public static void RegisterTask()
    {
        try
        {
            var taskRegistered = false;
            var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

            foreach (var task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
            {
                if (task.Value.Name == "ResponderBackgroundTask")
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(task.Value.Name + " Task Already Registered!!");
                    taskRegistered = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!taskRegistered)
            {
                builder.Name = "ResponderBackgroundTask";
                builder.TaskEntryPoint = "BackgroundGps.BackgroundTask";
                builder.AddCondition(new SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.UserNotPresent));
                builder.AddCondition(new SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.InternetAvailable));
                builder.SetTrigger(new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.UserAway, false));
                builder.CancelOnConditionLoss = true;
                var register = builder.Register();

                register.Completed += new BackgroundTaskCompletedEventHandler(OnComplete);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Here is the backgroundtask:

```
async public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    taskInstance.Canceled += new BackgroundTaskCanceledEventHandler(OnCanceled);

    Debug.WriteLine("Inside Run.......");

    BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

    await Geolocate();

    deferral.Complete();
}

async static Task<HttpResponseMessage> Geolocate()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Inside Async Geolocate");

    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

    Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
    geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = (PositionAccuracy) 20;
    geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 30;

    var networkStatus = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
    bool status = true;

    while (status)
    {
        networkStatus = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

        Geoposition position = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync().AsTask();

        var latitude = position.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude;
        var longitude = position.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.mylocation.com/location?=latitude&longitude");
        Debug.WriteLine(response);

        if (networkStatus == null)
        {
            status = false;
        }

        if (cancelRequest == true)
        {
            return response;
        }

        await Task.Delay(15000);
    }

    return response; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with background task in `UWP` project when I've used it for push notifications.

The main issue with `UWP` `BackgroundTasks` is that they suppose to be very light and consume not much of CPU time, otherwise the OS shuts it down.

My problem was, that I've tried to access the local database by using very heavy service, which took CPU time and were shutdown by the OS. My logs were cut in the middle of a line, cause my logger won't be fast enough to write the message.

Try to put some logs in your `BackgroundTask` inorder to see if he raised by the trigger, and look for a heavy operation that can cause it to be canceled.

Web requests can be also the problem...

Comment: Hey man, thank you the answer! I didn't think about background using too much CPU time. There is a weird behavior with the above code, if you notice the trigger that I am using is the "UserAway" trigger which is supposed trigger the task once the user is away or the device is locked. The weird thing is happening is that the task triggered on device lock, but it appears to stop the task thread. When unlocked, the background task continues to run when it shouldn't because this set condition "UserNotPresent". Have you seen this before or know what's happening?

Comment: I can see, that you run it on Windows 8.1, is it a phone/PC? Check if this link is relevant for you https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7b4a9862-63c1-4777-94de-60aef025010b/cannot-set-trigger-on-background-task-property-is-always-null?forum=wpdevelop   It's says that on Windows 8.1  " An app must be placed on the lock screen before it can successfully register background tasks using this trigger type."

Comment: This is just a PC app. Yes I have already place the app on the lock screen which is very vague by the way. When I first started on this I thought by "placing the app on the lock screen" meant having a badge on the actual lock screen, so the device is locked you can an icon there that's linked to your app. This is not the case lol. To make the app is always on the lock screen I've been using await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync() to request the user for access every time the app lauches. The link, i've seen already :) Thanks for your help though!!